# Is Soda Ash used in Tie Dying septic safe?

Tags: dye, dyeing

If I use soda ash when tie-dying, is it safe to dump the liquid down into my septic system or will it kill off?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the resources that I reviewed agree that the amount of soda ash used for home dyeing is safe to pour down the drain. However, I agree that it is important to take extra precautions with a septic system. So I checked the [Dharma Trading Co. website](http://www.dharmatrading.com/info/fiber-reactive-dye-general-information.html?lnav=techniques.html) (a great resource with lots of detailed info about dyeing fabric and fiber),

> One environmental consideration is that if you have added Soda Ash to your dyebath, then it's alkaline (high pH) and can be neutralized by the addition of a little white vinegar (low pH). If you used vinegar or acidic acid in your dyebath, you can add some Soda Ash to neutralize the acid.

They go on,

> Highly acidic or alkaline waste water maybe could upset the balance in a septic tank. We have pH test paper you can use to test the pH before flushing it down the drain.

So, I would recommend testing the pH of the leftover liquid, and, if it is overly alkaline, treating it with some white vinegar before you pour it down your drain.

Comment: Good information and backed up with external sources!